# How to disable buttons/ tabs until condition met

Tags: javascript, html

I'm making a game and i want my buttons to be disabled until a condition is met. Also my tabs.

I have tried

```
document.getElementById("Button").disabled = true;
```

but I cant get the button to be disabled. I am useing brackets editor and my "document" stuff and "window" stuff in javascript arnt working correctly I think.

This is my html code:

```
<span id="cookies">0</span>
                <br />
                <button onclick="cookieClick(1)">Click Me!</button>
                <br />
                Cost: 10 mp <button 
onclick="cookieClick(50)">BigClick</button>
                <br />
                Cost: <span id="cursorCost">10</span> <button 
onclick="buyCursor()">Buy Cursor</button>
                <br />
                Cost: <span id="catCost">50</span> <button 
onclick="buyCat()">Buy Cat</button>
                <br />
                Cost: <span id="dogCost">100</span> <button 
onclick="buyDog()">Buy Dog</button>
                <br />
                Cost: <span id="humanCost">200</span> <button 
onclick="buyHuman()">Buy Human</button>
                <br />
                Cost: <span id="rebirthCost">1000</span> <button 
onclick="buyRebirth()">Rebirth</button>
                <br />
```

this is my javascript code: (if i can get help with my functions to id appreciate it)

```
var cookies = 0;

function cookieClick(number) {
    cookies = cookies + number;
    document.getElementById("cookies").innerHTML = cookies;
}

function Bigclick(number) {
    if (rebirths < 1)
        cookies = cookies + number;
    document.getElementById("cookies").innerHTML = cookies;
}

var cursors = 0;

function buyCursor() {
    var cursorCost = Math.floor(10 * Math.pow(1.1, cursors)); //works out 
the cost of this cursor
    if (cookies <= 10)
        document.getElementById("cursorCost").disabled = true;
    if (cookies >= cursorCost) { //checks that the player can afford the 
cursor
        cursors = cursors + 1; //increases number of cursors
        cookies = cookies - cursorCost; //removes the cookies spent
        document.getElementById('cursors').innerHTML = cursors; //updates 
the number of cursors for the user
        document.getElementById('cookies').innerHTML = cookies; //updates 
the number of cookies for the user
    }
    var nextCost = Math.floor(10 * Math.pow(1.1, cursors)); //works out 
the cost of the next cursor
    document.getElementById('cursorCost').innerHTML = nextCost; //updates 
the cursor cost for the user
}
var cats = 0;

function buyCat() {
    var catCost = Math.floor(50 * Math.pow(1.1, cats)); //works out the 
cost of this cursor
    if (cookies >= catCost) { //checks that the player can afford the 
cursor
        cats = cats + 2; //increases number of cursors
        cookies = cookies - catCost; //removes the cookies spent
        document.getElementById('cats').innerHTML = cats; //updates the 
number of cursors for the user
        document.getElementById('cookies').innerHTML = cookies; //updates 
the number of cookies for the user
    }
    var nextCost = Math.floor(50 * Math.pow(1.1, cats)); //works out the 
cost of the next cursor
    document.getElementById('catCost').innerHTML = nextCost; //updates the 
cursor cost for the user
}
```

I expect my buyCursor button to be disabled until cookies>= cursorCost and my buyCat button to be disabled until cookies>= catCost . my output is the buttons are normal.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/nroujf  if i can get help with this to. on brackets editor all my documents.get things are not working i think

Comment: you didn't even call buyCursor function?

Comment: i did in my main code http://prntscr.com/nroz1y

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your js:

```
document.getElementById("cursorCost").disabled = true;
```

your html:

```
Cost: <span id="cursorCost">10</span> <button onclick="buyCursor()">Buy Cursor</button>
```

How can you find 'button'... T.T

Comment: i tried renaming it to  document.getElementById("buyCursor").disabled = true;                                     did not work. that's something i forgot to take out of my code because it doesn't do anything. none of the document stuff seems to be working

Comment: Are you sure there is 'id="buyCursor"' attribute in your button element which you want to be disabled?

Answer (score 1):

try

```js
Button.disabled = true;
```

```html
<button id="Button" >Click Me!</button>
```

Comment: yes i found that before but i want it disabled only while cookies< itemcost. how do i format that in javascript or html to work

Answer (score 1):

You made errors selecting the elements. Correct that.

You can either make all necessary button disabled by adding `disabled` attribute in HTML or can add it by JS.

I would suggest adding `disabled` in markup And then remove by JS.

```
Cost: <span id="cursorCost">10</span>
<button onclick="buyCursor()" disabled>Buy Cursor</button>
```

**Remove `disabled` attr with JS**

```
if (cookies >= cursorCost) { //checks that the player can afford the 
cursor

    //remove disabled attribute
document.getElementById("ID_OF_YOUR_BUTTON").removeAttribute("disabled");


    }
```

Comment: oh cool i didn't not think of this will try this now. prob with document.get thing tho is its saying its not defined in the brackets editor im useing http://prntscr.com/nrp1jc

Comment: http://prntscr.com/nrp3k2  nope they are all still disabled even if i set that condition sigh. can use cursors.get/ cursors.set instead of that document thing? or how do i get that to work

Answer (score 1):

You have done some mistakes in your code.

1. You are getting span id and trying to disable the button, instead you have to assign a id to button and access it.
2. You are calling disable function inside `buyCursor()` function which is wrong. you need to call that particular snippet outside that function.

I have done these in the following code.

> As suggested by `ShivCK` you can call disabled attribute even in the HTML itself

```js
var cookies = 0;
checkCursor()
function cookieClick(number) {
  cookies = cookies + number;
  document.getElementById("cookies").innerHTML = cookies;
  checkCursor()
}

function Bigclick(number) {
  if (rebirths < 1){
    cookies = cookies + number;
    document.getElementById("cookies").innerHTML = cookies;
  }
  checkCursor()
}

var cursors = 0;

function buyCursor() {
  var cursorCost = Math.floor(10 * Math.pow(1.1, cursors)); //works out the cost of this cursor
  if (cookies >= cursorCost) { //checks that the player can afford the cursor
    cursors = cursors + 1; //increases number of cursors
    cookies = cookies - cursorCost; //removes the cookies spent
    document.getElementById('cursors').innerHTML = cursors; //updates the number of cursors for the user
    document.getElementById('cookies').innerHTML = cookies; //updates the number of cookies for the user
  }
  var nextCost = Math.floor(10 * Math.pow(1.1, cursors)); //works out 
  //the cost of the next cursor
  document.getElementById('cursorCost').innerHTML = nextCost; //updates the cursor cost for the user
}
var cats = 0;

function buyCat() {
  var catCost = Math.floor(50 * Math.pow(1.1, cats)); //works out the cost of this cursor
  if (cookies >= catCost) { //checks that the player can afford the cursor
  cats = cats + 2; //increases number of cursors
  cookies = cookies - catCost; //removes the cookies spent
  document.getElementById('cats').innerHTML = cats; //updates the number of cursors for the user
  document.getElementById('cookies').innerHTML = cookies; //updates the number of cookies for the user
  }
  var nextCost = Math.floor(50 * Math.pow(1.1, cats)); //works out the cost of the next cursor
  document.getElementById('catCost').innerHTML = nextCost; //updates the cursor cost for the user
  checkCursor()
}

function checkCursor(){
  if (cookies <= 10){
    document.getElementById("cursorCostBtn").disabled = true;
  } else {
    document.getElementById("cursorCostBtn").disabled = false;
  }
  
  if (cookies <= 50){
    document.getElementById("catCostBtn").disabled = true;
  } else {
    document.getElementById("catCostBtn").disabled = false;
  }
  
  if (cookies <= 100){
    document.getElementById("dogCostBtn").disabled = true;
  } else {
    document.getElementById("dogCostBtn").disabled = false;
  }
  
  if (cookies <= 200){
    document.getElementById("humanCostBtn").disabled = true;
  } else {
    document.getElementById("humanCostBtn").disabled = false;
  }
  
  if (cookies <= 1000){
    document.getElementById("rebirthCostBtn").disabled = true;
  } else {
    document.getElementById("rebirthCostBtn").disabled = false;
  }
}
```

```html
<span id="cookies">0</span><br />

<button onclick="cookieClick(1)">Click Me!</button><br />

Cost: 50 <button onclick="cookieClick(50)">BigClick</button><br />

Cost: <span id="cursorCost">10</span> <button id="cursorCostBtn"
onclick="buyCursor()">Buy Cursor</button><br />

Cost: <span id="catCost">50</span> <button onclick="buyCat()" id="catCostBtn">Buy Cat</button><br />

Cost: <span id="dogCost">100</span> <button onclick="buyDog()" id="dogCostBtn">Buy Dog</button><br />

Cost: <span id="humanCost">200</span> <button onclick="buyHuman()" id="humanCostBtn">Buy Human</button><br />

Cost: <span id="rebirthCost">1000</span> <button onclick="buyRebirth()" id="rebirthCostBtn" >Rebirth</button><br />
```

Comment: o wow that worked thats. now i can do that for every button. would that work for my tabs to? how would i disabled being able to click on a tab http://prntscr.com/nrp6iv         http://prntscr.com/nrp6n9

Comment: yes just do like the same with your tabs too. that will work

Comment: is there a way to make that if statement                                                                  
                                                                                                                                 
         if (cookies <= cursorCost){
                 document.getElementById("cursorCostBtn").disabled = true;
                        } else {
                    document.getElementById("cursorCostBtn").disabled = false;
                 }
               }

Comment: because the cost is changeing everytime you buy it. i tred that in my editor didnt work so it must have to be formated diffrently

Comment: no you have to reset your cookies to 0, when you buy it

Comment: so i have this http://prntscr.com/o0pvtd http://prntscr.com/o0pvva  http://prntscr.com/o0pw1x  . i want these hidden until a condition is met. for some reason i cant get this to work. i want all tabs hidden until certain conditions are met.